Cannot connect to Docker Postgresql Database in Spring Boot Application
I'm new to Spring Boot Development in Visual Studio Code and I am trying to follow a tutorial on how to connect to Docker Postgresql Database in a Spring Boot Project.
Link to the tutorial: https://youtu.be/Nv2DERaMx-4?t=5395
When I try to run the project, these are the errors I received:
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:444) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at com.juno.postgresqldatabase.PostgresqldatabaseApplication.run(PostgresqldatabaseApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at com.juno.postgresqldatabase.PostgresqldatabaseApplication.main(PostgresqldatabaseApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]

org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:84) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:388) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:444) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at com.juno.postgresqldatabase.PostgresqldatabaseApplication.run(PostgresqldatabaseApplication.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunner$5(SpringApplication.java:790) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.acceptWithException(ThrowingConsumer.java:83) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:60) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingConsumer$1.accept(ThrowingConsumer.java:88) ~[spring-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:798) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:789) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.lambda$callRunners$3(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:357) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:510) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:774) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:341) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
        at com.juno.postgresqldatabase.PostgresqldatabaseApplication.main(PostgresqldatabaseApplication.java:22) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "helpme"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:659) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:180) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291) ~[postgresql-42.5.0.jar:42.5.0]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:160) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:118) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
        ... 23 common frames omitted

This is my code:
PostgresqldatabaseApplication.java
package com.juno.postgresqldatabase;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@SpringBootApplication
@Log
public class PostgresqldatabaseApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    public PostgresqldatabaseApplication(final DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PostgresqldatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        log.info("data source: " + this.dataSource.toString());
        final JdbcTemplate restTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.dataSource);
        restTemplate.execute("select 1");
    }

}

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.juno</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresqldatabase</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>postgresqldatabase</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        <version>42.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>       
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

application.properties
spring.application.name=postgresqldatabase
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=changemeinprod!
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.postgresql.Driver

docker-compose.yml
version: '3.1'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432-5432"
    restart: always
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: changemeinprod!

I've tried to change the pg_hba.conf file:
Changing md5 -> password
This is the result after I run the command docker-compose up:
Run database using Docker
I've also try to add other plug-ins:
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
                <version>1.3</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
</plugin>

Changing the versions around, and many more but nothing seems to work. Please tell me where the problem lie.

It looks like your application is trying to connect on the database using a different user than you configured? FATAL: password authentication failed for user "helpme" your configuration suggests you should be using postgres instead

I see a few issues with your docker compose file

port is in the wrong format for your use case. It should be like this: 5432:5432
the environment is an array, not an object, and each item should be in the format key=value.
You dont have any volume configured, so postgres will have nowhere to store the data.

Try following this tutorial for how to deploy postgres using docker compose
https://geshan.com.np/blog/2021/12/docker-postgres/
You can see the docker-compose.yaml from this tutorial and you'll see the issues with your docker file
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    volumes: 
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  db:
    driver: local

Finally I would say that before you try to connect to your database in a Spring Boot application, I would make sure you can connect to it using a command line tool like psql or a GUI tool like pgAdmin4 or DataGrip. This will save you a lot of time chasing your tail and its also very useful to have a separate tool to analyze your database.
Good luck.

note: the dash on the port specification for a container is not exactly wrong, the way OP used it means a range (I know of one port) but without external mapping. It doesn't cause an error, but your point stands as it will definitely not behave as intended. Cheers

Thanks, updated to indicate that it's wrong specifically for this use case and not generally :)

I'm not used to configure the database in Docker and .yml file format was kinda new to me, so there were a lot to figure out and navigate.
Thank you so much, I managed to connect to postgresql now. I hope that you have a great day!

@JunoLee I'm glad you were able to figure it out! If you dont mind, would you please mark this answer as correct? I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you!
